# How to assign portion of 2D array to CUDA streams?

Tags: cuda

Allocating some portion of 1D to stream is easy,we can have base pointer to chunk as one of the argument of kernel but how to achieve same thing in 2D array,seems difficult because in 2D array chunk can be itself 2D array so how to manage pointer in this case?Please help

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense. Streams are a driver side FIFO mechanism for performing simultaneous operations (memory transfers and/or kernel execution) on the GPU. They have nothing to do with device memory allocation or addressing _per se_. Please edit your question to clarify what it is you are asking.

Comment: Have u worked with streams before?when we allocate some portion of array to stream "i" we pass base pointer as argument to kernel so that stream i will operate on it's portion of array...this is easy in 1D array but how to do this in 2D array?

Comment: What is (by your definition) a "2D array"? Is it pitched linear memory, or is it an array of pointers?

Comment: @talonmies what happened?still question not clear to you?

Comment: @username_4567 I have never used streams, I'm about to do it soon. But as **talonmies** says it is better to used a linearized version of the matrix (or what he calls a pitched linear memory). I have been working with 2D matrices that are made of vector of vectors and in the end I always linearized memory is easy to use and is better for performance and CUDA.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, streams is completely irrelevant to your question, they have no bearing on what you are asking about.

If you actually allocated a device array of pointers, then you must already have a host array containing device row or column pointers. If your algorithm works so that each kernel launch (or block inside the launch) processes memory contained within a single allocation (so a row or a column), then you can pass each row or column pointer as a argument at each launch. If a given launch requires accessing memory across multiple rows or columns, the only solution is to pass the whole array of pointers, along with a tuple containing the entry points to the array for each kernel launch.

Be warned that using arrays of pointers in CUDA is a very poor idea in 90% of real world applications. The performance in non trivial cases is considerably worse that using pitched linear memory (you are effectively doubling memory access latency for each additional level of pointer indirection you add to data to be read and written inside a kernel). The few IOPs it takes to do indexing inside a kernel are far less expensive. Using arrays of pointers also makes host and device much more complex than it needs to be in most cases.